# How to create gRPC server in Windows Form App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, grpc

I start to explore gRPC in C#. I try to build gRPC  serwer in Windows Forms App. I used belowe code  to create and start gRPC server. But  I encountered a problem.

> Exception User-UnHandled
> System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind port "localhost:30057"'

Code in class Form1:

```
using Grpc.Core;
using GrpcConsoleServer;

namespace WinFormGrpcServerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int Port = 30057;// Number of Server Port             
            Server server = new Server //Create instance of Server
            {                
                Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterServer()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Greeter server isting on port" + Port);
        }
    }
}

Project: Windows Forms App
Framework: .NET 7.0
Packages:
Google.Protobuf (3.20.1)
Grpc (2.46.1)
Grpc.Tools(2.46.1)
```

It is possible create qRPC Server in Windows Forms App? I don't know what is wrong, i can't find i web any tips.

Comment: restart the computer the port is closed, probably because y ou the code alreday

Comment: Of course i tried restart the computer, changed port nr.
 Used code without problem work in Console Application.
So i wonder it is possible create qRPC Server in Windows Forms App?

Comment: you need to stop the server as well before shutting the program

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is because the server instance lives shortly, inside the click handler. After a while, the garbage collection will flush it away. That's block you to connect in any way.

Let's try to rewrite the class:

```
namespace WinFormGrpcServerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Server _server;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._server != null)
            {
                throw new Exception();  //choose something meaningful
            }

            const int Port = 30057;// Number of Server Port             
            this._server = new Server //Create instance of Server
            {                
                Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterServer()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
            this._server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Greeter server isting on port" + Port);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, it's your job to dispose/close the server when the program closes (although it probably will do by itself).

Comment: Thank You very much for help.
Problem was occured, because my program was simple and don't have nessesey protection.  So after double click button i  runned server secend time.
Now every think is ok and i continue my trip.
Once else  thank You very much.